# Embedding uncountably many disjoint copies of the Cantor set in the interval

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is it possible to embed uncountably many copies of the Cantor set in the unit interval so that any two are disjoint?

Comment: The answer is yes: if $C$ is the Cantor set, then $C\times C$ is made up of uncountably copies of $C$, and is homeomorphic to $C$. So $C\times C$ embeds into the unit interval.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answered in the comments.

Comment: You could have sent it to MathSE instead of closing it... (I voted to move it on MathSE, which is not apparent in the "put on hold as off-topic" written above)

Comment: @YCor Recent discussion on meta suggests that migration to MSE is not always optimal thing to do. Link: [Migrating to Math.SE: too many close reasons](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2319/migrating-to-math-se-too-many-close-reasons)

Comment: @YCor to emphasis the above comment, this question is *not* suitable for [math.se] as is, as it lacks context. It might well be closed and in any case is not a good on-topic question there.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'm aware that the choice of migrating to MathSE is nontrivial but I considered this post as a reasonable math question, correctly written, and not stupid (well, the product trick makes the answer trivial but it's understandable not to find it if one's not familiar to the abstract definitions of Cantor set), and definitely not of research level. Anyway if the opinion of the other who closed is different, I'm fine with this.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  The Cantor set is homeomorphic to the space $C=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology and the product gets the product topology.
Now $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is homeomorphic to the square $C^2$.
Hence $C^2$ embeds into the unit interval.
Clearly, $C^2$ is the disjoint union of uncountably many Cantor sets.